# Remove All Permission In SSRS 2008

Tags: vb.net, t-sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Must remove all the permissions SSRS 2008 all reports and leave only one group, is there any way via script in PS, VB, T-SQL that performs this task?

Comment: If you want to start with a fresh SSRS instance, why not reinstalling it? It would be faster and cleaner than deleting everything.

Comment: The RDL files I need to keep, I will remove the permissions and granting some specific, matter of organization.

Comment: ok so you want to remove the permissions but leave all the reports deployed on the report server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see 2 ways of doing it:

**The recommended (supported) way**

Go through all reports and restore the parent security.
This can take a lot of time depending on the number or reports you have.

**The unsupported way**

This should do what you want without too much work, but is quite risky.

1. Backup your ReportServer DB (**important**)
2. Apply the permissions you want on the root in the web interface
3. Go in the `Catalog` table and look for the `PolicyID` of the corresponding entry (it should be the first line, with almost all other columns = `NULL`, and `PolicyRoot` = `1`)
4. Execute the following query:
   `update [dbo].[Catalog] set [PolicyID] = <YourRootPolicyID>`
5. (Optional) Clean the `PolicyUserRole` table, which maps a user to a role and a policy:
   `delete from [dbo].[PolicyUserRole] where [PolicyID] <> <YourRootPolicyID>`
6. (Optional) Clean the `Policies` table, which holds the list of policies (= security settings):
   `delete from [dbo].[Policies] where [PolicyID] <> <YourRootPolicyID>`

All your items will now have same the security settings.